# MYSQL, multiple joins and grouping together

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm scratching my head trying to figure out a way to bring back the data I need. These are the tables I've got:

```
**Parts**
 partcode   description

 chicken      foo
 pork         bar
 beef         meh

**Pictures**
partcode     picdata

chicken      010101
pork         <no record>
beef         010101

**Prices**
partcode     price1         price2

chicken      10.00           10.50
pork         11.00           11.50
beef         12.00           12.50

**Customer_Prices**
partcode     custid         cusprice

chicken      JIM            8.50
pork         JIM            <no record>
beef         JIM            7.22
chicken      BOB            8.99
pork         BOB            8.99
beef         BOB            <no record>
```

What I'm trying to do is bring back all stock records and the various different prices, including Nulls if they aren't there! What I'm actually getting currently is lots of repeated stock codes as different rows with different price values in there. So my desired results would be something like (assuming I've gone with customer code as JIM

```
**Results**
partcode   description  picture  price1 price2 cusprice

chicken     foo          010101   10.00  10.50  8.50
pork        bar           NULL    11.00  11.50  NULL
beef        meh          010101   12.00  12.50  7.22
```

I'm currently using left outer joins on all tables, this is bringing back multiple entries for chicken and treating the prices as different rows all together.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Do the LEFT JOIN version, but also add a GROUP BY yo get only one cusprice per partcode.

Comment: The problem seems to be, if i do a left join, and then a WHERE clause for the customer, it only returns rows where there is a specific customer price, id like to to return ALL products, prices and a customer price if there is one, otherwise a NULL.

Comment: Use ON clause instead of WHERE clause for the LEFT JOIN-ed table conditions.

Comment: I think thats the one I needed! I did ON cp.partcode = pr.partcode and cp.custid = 'JIM' and it looks to be what I need. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

You can use such a statement containing `INNER JOIN`s :

```
SELECT pr.partcode, pr.description, pc.picdata, ps.price1, ps.price2, cp.cusprice 
  FROM parts pr 
  JOIN pictures pc ON pc.partcode = pr.partcode
  JOIN prices ps ON ps.partcode = pr.partcode
  JOIN customer_prices cp ON cp.partcode = pr.partcode
 WHERE cp.custid = 'JIM';
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=269c59dbf75339fe29376a8ab9bf0a4e)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunatly, this doesnt bring back some rows. In the case of 'JIM', it would not bring back rows for pork, presumably where there is no cusprice record for him for that product.

Comment: this works if i change:
 ON cp.partcode = pr.partcode
 WHERE cp.custid = 'JIM'
To:
 ON cp.partcode = pr.partcode
 and cp.custid = 'JIM'

Comment: Hi @EdJones, you're welcome. Depending on the sample data, the query containing INNER JOIN should work for you(Consider the Demo I just added into the answer). If some partcode values are missing for the consequent tables(pictures ,prices, customer_prices ), then you can replace JOIN keywords with `LEFT JOIN`s. Tell me whether you have other sample  values which should be added.